# Brute force counter measures not effective?

Tags: php, security, authentication

Hello everyone sorry to bother but I've been for ages trying to figure out why my brute force countermeasures aren't working according to my offline security scanner.  It keeps firing random user/pass combinations even when my code works like this:

PAGE A (UNSENSITIVE AREA) Main.php
A CSRF & Captcha protected form waits for user input.
If no CSRF attack detected, valid captcha and destination is selected (there are 3 pages that might be destination OR Login) the form leads you to for example to page B login as follows:

PAGE B LOGIN.php
This page reads Referer, if valid according to my programming does as follows:
Common form user/pass/captcha/csrf key checked against database;

```
if($userisfound==1)
{
echo 'welcome to our site';
}       
else { 
$_SESSION['attempt'] = (!$_SESSION['attempt']) ? 0 : $_SESSION['attempt'];
if($_POST['username']){$_SESSION['attempt']++;}
if($_SESSION['attempt'] > 20) 
{header('location:isolated.php');exit;}
}
```

PAGE C ISOLATED.php

```
<?php session_start(); session_unset(); session_destroy();
sleep(99999);
header(location:http://www.thanks.ty);
die;
?>
```

Please can you guys assess me in what am I doing wrong?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I'd just attack the site via cURL, which is going to get a new session cookie for every request, making your protection useless. I'd also use your `isolated.php` to crash the server, as hitting it a few dozen times will tie up all of your Apache workers if you're using that webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problems:

#### #1: You're using session cookies

You're basing it off sessions without blocking a specific IP. Sessions are connected to a client by a session cookie, if they delete this, then the session doesn't exist and therefore the attempts don't. Most vulnerability scanners won't keep session cookies. attempts.

#### #2: You unset the session on `isolated.php`

Essentially what happens is `isolated.php` just runs on your server and it doesn't hault the client at all. The client doesn't have to wait for the page to load before attempting to load another page after that. Essentially, it just wastes time on your server and nothing else.

## What should you do?

1. Grab the user IP (Plenty of tutorials around for that)
2. Create a SQL database to store attempts based off IP. Essentially run `UPDATE attempts SET attempts=attempts+1 WHERE ip = [THE_IP]` every time there is an incorrect attempt at a user or user `INSERT` if there is no attempts already.
3. Query the database to check if there is the current user IP > 20 attempts.
4. Block the user if there is more than 20 attempts based off the info in the DB.

Comment: To be honest that was the way of handling bad login attempts initially but since the whole company will share same public ip, just requires one user having a bad day and the whole company might get locked for X minutes.  Another ideal solution could be catch their Mac address via arp but with all this easy mac-spoof going on...
Anyway definitely I'm rolling back to database logging and countermeasures.
You've helped me a lot, specially with the (sleep) part, since I thought a connection might get frozen during such amount of time.
Thank you very much 4 real.